# Yolk crashes when PyPi package descriptions contain certain characters

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, character-encoding, pypi, yolk

[Yolk](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yolk3k/0.8.7) (0.8.7) reports and encoding error when printing information about packages. For example, when I

```sh
yolk -M crypto-enigma
```

I get

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u03b2' in
>   position 2322: ordinal not in range(128)

because the [PyPi page for the package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/crypto-enigma) has a `β` in it. Or if I try

```sh
yolk -M Metafone
```

I get

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 3291-3292: ordinal not in range(128)

Is there a way to avoid this error? It seems like a bug that Yolk would crash just because there's a Greek character or mathematical symbol in the PyPi page for a package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, which manifests only in Python 2.x, fixed in versions >= 0.8.8  (see [fc842a3](https://github.com/myint/yolk/commit/fc842a30236b9d5cfda07028150f97e42afa5a1d)).

Comment: I'd just add that the command to upgrade is `sudo pip install --upgrade yolk3k`